# Bars rendered outside graph with NumericEndPointsTickProviderSpec in charts_flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I'm having this behavior in a BarChart from [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) package.

[image]

which is rendered with the following code:

```
  return Center(
    child: Container(
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      child: new charts.BarChart(
        series,
        vertical: false,
        primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
          tickProviderSpec: charts.NumericEndPointsTickProviderSpec(),
        ),
        domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

where `series` contais a list of data points between 4951 and 5030.

I don't know why bars are rendered outside the chart limits, starting from the very left without respecting its wrapping container limits.

If I remove the `tickProviderSpec` setting the bars are rendered inside, as I expected earlier, but I lose the ticks customization that I wanted to achieve in the first place.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using StaticNumericTickProviderSpec, pass in a list of TickSpec(n) with n being some integer value..